# Django rest framework - Many to One relationship using 2 separate type of serializers?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a user serializer. The user has a many to one relationship with a company.

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = "__all__"

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [...fields..., "company"]
```

The get request will return the json like:

```
{
   "username" : "...",
   ...other fields...,
   company: {
      ...company fields...
   }
}
```

The company cannot be empty. A user always has a company.

When I try to create a user by sending a json like:

```
{
   "username" : "...",
   ...other fields...,
   company: 1
}
```

I would imagine that this would link the user with the company 1, but it tells me: `null value in column "company_id" violates not-null constraint`. Is is possible to include the model in get requests, but create a user using the primary key?

Do I need two separate serializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set the company as read only fields it will not accept any value, due to which company value is null.

Your requirement is that you need an int value in a field value and return the object, there is no such field provided by DRF, but you can create a custom field, which will accept int and return the dict object

```
class CustomForeignKeyField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset

    def to_representation(self, value):
        value = super().to_representation(value)
        company = Company.objects.get(pk=value)
        return CompanySerializer(user).data
```

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CustomForeignKeyField(querset=Company.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [...fields..., "company"]
```

Comment: This seems to have a weird side effect. When I implemented this, it expects my `fields` fields to be the fields of my company. So this is the error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: ...company fields...
[20/Nov/2019 12:28:52] "GET /.../users/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 500 22913`.

Comment: can you add company model, it seems like some column name is missing

Comment: Yup thanks! I used `pk` instead of `id`. I forgot that my id was named `idcompany`